# Mobile safari crash log - low memory

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios7, mobile-safari, crash-reports

I have a web app that occasionally falls over on start up on Mobile Safari (only for an iPhone4s, however, bizarrely it's fine with an iPhone4).

I know it's a low memory issue but I am new to deciphering crash logs.

I am getting the following in the log:

```
 Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max   fds      [reason]          (state)
MobileSafari <6668023ea0673cda85a45ba6eea56202>        77461            77461  100   [vm-pageshortage]  (audio) (frontmost) (resume)
```

Does the (audio) reference under the (state) section mean that the crash is occuring when it's try to play / download / do something with a sound file, or is it not possible to tell the exact cause of the crash?

Also any ideas why this would only happen on a 4s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the download of the game's .mp3 file that was causing the crash.  The original file was 1.3mb and once reduced to 0.3mb, the game no longer crashed.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem with a website that was crushing mobile safari.
tested it on IOS6 and IOS7.

In my case it was CSS3 transform (-webkit-transform) property.

It seems like i had too much elements that i needed them to be hardware accelerated.

i wrote a post about it in my blog: 
http://www.dimshik.com/ios-7-runs-out-of-memory-when-using-webkit-transform/

also there is an example i have created that makes the mobile safari crash: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/dJLhh/8/

```
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: I have answered my own question now (the damn audio file), but thanks for your help!